# Right click menu in Nemo missing 'create shortcut' and 'copy/move to'

Tags: file-copy, menu, nemo, desktop-shortcuts

I recently did a clean install of Linux Mint 17.3 with Cinnamon on my machine.

Before the clean install, if I right clicked on a file or folder in nemo, the menu would have a 'create shortcut' option. Now after the clean install, that option isn't there. I've gone through the nemo preferences and I can't find any option to enable it.

After some searching I found out a keyboard shortcut for making file shortcuts in nemo (`ctrl`+`shift`+click and drag), but I'd much rather the more intuitive (and memorable) right click menu option.

Similarly, other right click options that are now missing are

- `copy to`

  - `other pane`
  - `home`
  - `Downloads`
  - etc
- `move to`

  - `other pane`
  - `home`
  - `Downloads`
  - etc

How can I get those options back as well?

I've tried searching through the Nemo preferences, but to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you right click the file or folder in Nemo, there will be a `+` sign at the top. Clicking that will expand the menu and give you the options you want.

For what it's worth, I found this functionality at this link:

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=212256

[image: Default]

[image: Expanded]

Comment: Yep, that works.

I just assumed that + was to change the default 'open with' application, or something like that.

Comment: This doesn't work for creating link. When I want t  create a link I want to select (copy) a file, go to destination then create a link.  Right now this is more like right click to create a link, copy it, cut it (does nothing) go to the destination paste it (this automatically deletes the link). not intuitive at all

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it worked for me in the past. However, it doesn't work for me anymore. It turns out that for later versions of Nemo (ex: v5.2.4), you must follow [this answer now instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/577150/114401).

Answer (score 7):

In LinuxMint 19.3's Nemo (4.4-4.4.2), you must now follow these steps:

1. Open Nemo (Type Nemo into the Start Menu).
2. Click "Edit" and then "Preferences" at the bottom of the drop down menu.
3. A new window will open, left click the row item titled "Context Menu".
4. You will now be able to add or remove context menu options. See the image below for more information:

[image: Screenshot of Context Menu Offered by Nemo (4.4.2)]

I found this out after not seeing anything remotely similar to what other answers have provided for past versions of Nemo.

Comment: (Tested on Ubuntu 22.04 with Nemo 5.2.4). For anyone wondering, the boxes _not_ initially checked by default include `Duplicate`, `Make Link`, `Copy to`, and `Move to`. The one you need to ensure is selected here is `Make Link`. I just checked all of the boxes though, as that's what I'm accustomed to seeing in the right-click menu on older versions of Nemo.

Answer (score 1):

You can drag the source file(s) over the target folder and press the ALT key (a small question mark appears). When you release the mouse button a pop-up menu appears including 'Link here'.

Answer (score 1):

If you are lazy like me, paste the following commands in the terminal.

```
gsettings set org.nemo.preferences.menu-config selection-menu-make-link true
gsettings set org.nemo.preferences.menu-config selection-menu-copy-to true
gsettings set org.nemo.preferences.menu-config selection-menu-move-to true
```

It basically goes to
<kbd><kbd>Edit</kbd>
  >  <kbd>Preferences</kbd>
  >  <kbd>Context Menu</kbd></kbd>

And Check:

- Make Link
- Copy to
- Move to

Comment: Is it also possible the path of the file or folder to clibboard from the context menu?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you just need to copy the file(s) and paste it in a text file. It will paste the path of the file(s).

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Nemo in Mint Xfce 19.2 and I see no expandable + sing in the context menu. But the options can be enabled by simply going to  *Edit - Use full context menu*.

[image]